# Print anything between two delimiters

Tags: sed

I need to print a line with any matches occurrences between '

This is my source line:

```
(2,'one.com',0,NULL,1,1,1,0),(3,'two.com',0,NULL,1,1,1,0),(4,'three.com',0,NULL,1,1,1,0),(5,'four.com',0,NULL,0,1,1,0),(6,'five.com',0,NULL,0,1,1,0), etc....
```

I need to print only:

```
one.com
two.com
three.com
four.com
five.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use this `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=')[^']*(?=',)" file
one.com
two.com
three.com
four.com
five.com
```

It prints from a given `'` up to next `',`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk` to get the info:

```
awk -v RS=\' 'NR%2==0' file
one.com
two.com
three.com
four.com
five.com
```

It will print all fro start `'` to stop `'`

Can also be written like this:

```
awk '!(NR%2)' RS=\' file
```